# Sqlite DatabaseHelper. make a return method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

How do I make a method in my databaseHelper (that extends from SQLiteOpenHelper) class that returns a string for some data of a user.

For example

```
public String getUserPassword (String username){

    ..
    return password;
}
```

I just don't know how to make a Cursor that Search for the username (which is the primary key) and find the same user then return his password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method `rawQuery()` of the `SQLiteDatabase` class which returns a `Cursor`.
 
For this method you must pass 2 arguments:

- the sql statement which is a `SELECT` statement
- an array containing the username's value which will be used in the `WHERE` clause to return the password
  (if it exists).

---

This method will return the password or `null` if the username is not found in the table:

```
public String getUserPassword (String username){
    String password = null;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "SELECT password FROM tablename WHERE username = ?"; 
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(sql, new String[] {username});
    if (c.moveToNext()) password = c.getString(0);
    c.close();
    db.close();
    return password;
}
```

In this line:

```
String sql = "SELECT password FROM tablename WHERE username = ?";
```

change the names of the table and the columns to the names that you have in your database.

Comment: so when i need to call this method from fragment , How to do it?

Comment: i try this but it's give me an error says the method not static.  email=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.emailA2);
        email.setText(DatabaseHelper.getemail(username));

Comment: This error is not relevant to the question you posted in which you asked for a method to retrieve the user's password. So if you have another issue post a new question, including the code where the error is thrown.